# Features as input of neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is how I define a neural network

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyFun:
    def __init__(self, x, y, sizes, activations, scope):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            last_out = tf.concat([x, y], axis=1)
            for l, size in enumerate(sizes):
                last_out = tf.layers.dense(last_out, size, activation=activations[l])
            self.vars = tf.trainable_variables(scope=scope)
            self.output = last_out
```

I need to use preprocess input `x` and `y` (both placeholders) into features before feeding them into the network. More specifically, I want to use quadratic features, i.e.,

`new_input = [1, x, y, x**2, y**2, cross(x,y)]`

where `cross(x,y)` includes the product between all elements of `[x, y]`, i.e.,

`cross(x,y) = [x_1*x_2, x_1*x_3, ..., x_1*y_1, ...]`

How can I do it elegantly? Is there an equivalent of `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```py
# Suppose your placeholders are one dimensional vectors, with sizes 3 and 7:
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[7])

# concat the constant 1.0 with x and y:
z = tf.concat((tf.constant(1.0,shape=(1,)),x,y),axis=0)

# construct all products of pairs:    
new_input = [z[i]*z[j] for i in range(3+7-1) for j in range(i,3+7)]

# convert the list of tensors to a tensor (optional):
new_input = tf.stack(new_input)
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Extending this to the case where `x` and `y` have a batch dimension:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,7])

# I use 1.0+0*x[:,:1] instead of tf.constant(1.0)
z = tf.concat((1.0+0*x[:,:1],x,y),axis=1)

new_input = [z[:,i]*z[:,j] for i in range(3+7-1) for j in range(i,3+7)]    
new_input = tf.stack(new_input,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my placeholders `x` and `y` have shape `(?,constant)`, not `(constant)` and `tf.concat` gives me an error. How do I fix it?

Comment: I updated the answer, although I admit that this solution is not very elegant. I hope it solves your problem though.